# spring actuator logfile colorization ANSI

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to use actuator to get logfile by request and this work fine. I would like to show it on a html screen to manage multiple spring applications with same aspect as in a run console IDE.

But I make some tests to received the file with charset encode ANSI to get also the colorization and this not work

Tests are made with change in application.yaml like this

`logging charset: file: windows-1252`

or

`spring: output: ansi: enabled: always`

But nothing append or change in the request response, no special chars :-(

Is it possible to have colorization ANSI with /logfile request ?
It should be great to specify a request parameter encode response to ANSI or something like this

Thanks for your help